# MDT Module Updating Media through JEA Endpoint fails adding BCD entry

Tags: powershell, mdt

I am running into an issue with remotely updating MDT offline media on a JEA endpoint. The error has something to do with permissions passed to BCDEdit and the virtual account created by JEA (WinRM User...). BCDEdit returns

> An error occurred while attempting the specified create operation.  This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object.

when trying to update the BCD file with the x64 boot config.

Command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DeploymentServerName -ConfigurationName MDTUpdate -ScriptBlock { 
        New-PSDrive -Name "DS002" -PSProvider MDTProvider -Root "$Using:LocalDeploymentShareFolder" -ErrorAction Stop
        Update-MDTMedia -Path "DS002:\Media\MEDIA001" -Verbose
    } -Credential $MDTCreds -ErrorAction Stop
```

Command that MDT module runs:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\AMD64\BCDBoot\bcdedit.exe' -store "C:\MyVMs\MDT\USB\Content\Boot\bcd" /create "{f31cce1a-e314-4481-9ac9-e519f65dff65}" -d "Litetouch Boot [MEDIA001] (x64)" -application OSLOADER
```

Error from JEA Transcript:

```
VERBOSE: Error detected running command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\AMD64\BCDBoot\bcdedit.exe -store "C:\MyVMs\MDT\USB\Content\Content\Boot\bcd" /create "{f31cce1a-e314-4481-9ac9-e519f65dff65}" -d "Litetouch Boot [MEDIA001] (x64)" -application OSLOADER' Exit code is: 1
VERBOSE: Error text is: An error occurred while attempting the specified create operation.  This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object.
Update-MDTMedia : BcdEdit returned an error.
At line:5 char:9
+         Update-MDTMedia -Path "DS002:\Media\MEDIA001" -Verbose
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MEDIA001:String) [Update-MDTMedia], DeploymentPointException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BcdEditError,Microsoft.BDD.PSSnapIn.GenerateMDTMedia
```

Relevant information from session config:

```
@{
    SchemaVersion = '2.0.0.0'
    SessionType = 'Default'
    ExecutionPolicy = 'Unrestricted'
    LanguageMode = 'FullLanguage'
    TranscriptDirectory = 'C:\JEA\Transcripts'
    RunAsVirtualAccount = $true
    RoleDefinitions = @{
        'ExampleDomain\ExampleUserOrGroup' = @{
            'RoleCapabilities' = 'MDTUpdate'  
        } 
    }
}
```

Relevant content from role config:

```
@{
ModulesToImport = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Deployment Toolkit\Bin\MicrosoftDeploymentToolkit.psd1'
VisibleCmdlets = 'Get-Command','Out-Default','Exit-PSSession','Measure-Object','Select-Object','Get-FormatData','Start-Transcript','Stop-Transcript','Import-Module','Get-Module','New-PSDrive','Write-Output','Update-MDTDeploymentShare','Remove-Item','Update-MDTMedia','New-Item','Remove-PSDrive'
VisibleProviders = 'FileSystem', 'MDTProvider'
VisibleExternalCommands = 'bcdedit.exe'
}
```

How can I give BCDEdit the proper permissions when running under the virtual account? Or do I have to drop JEA and give a service account local admin rights and run it under the default PSSession?

Comment: I worked around this splitting the x86 and x64 media, so that BCDEdit didn't have to run. But still looking for a way to fix Virtual JEA account permissions if there is a way.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that comes to mind, is make sure that the group that the account is a part of, has more than just Read-Only permissions. I've had a case where I could run any powershell command, but when it came to invoking a non-powershell native program, it would give me permission issues.

The only other thing besides that is to use a runas within the script block, but that kinda goes against the whole purpose of JEA.

Comment: I think you might be on to something here, I assumed that administrators had full control to bcdedit. But looks like the exe only has Read & Execute for admins. I'll need to run another Build Task to verify, but this may be it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue. `VERBOSE: Error detected running command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment 
Tools\AMD64\BCDBoot\bcdedit.exe -store "C:\MyVMs\MDT\USB\Content\Boot\bcd" 
/create "{d158c079-c7c7-4204-b3d5-8060fef07b48}" -d "Litetouch Boot [MEDIA001] 
(x64)" -application OSLOADER' Exit code is: 1
VERBOSE: Error text is: An error occurred while attempting the specified create
 operation.  This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object. `